# Large config file and memory in Perl

Tags: perl

In an accountancy program in Perl, we have the following lines in CONFIG.pm:

```
if ($user == 1)
{
    $conf{'name'}       = 'Procon, Inc.';
    $conf{'vatnr'}      = '487520658';
    $conf{'conditions'} = 'long html';
}
if ($user == 2)
{
    $conf{'name'}       = 'E.B.X., Inc.';
    $conf{'vatnr'}      = '302632599';
    $conf{'conditions'} = 'other long html';
}
```

The `$conf{'conditions'}` variable takes a lot of place, makes CONFIG.pm less readable and is actually only needed when generating invoices/quotes.

Over the years, CONFIG.pm has grown to >2MB which is probably considerable regarding memory, given the fact that every single Perl file must first load it.

In regard to memory, would it be better to leave out `$conf{'conditions'}` ? And put them inside /config/conditions/client1.html, and read it out only when it needs to be put on an invoice/quotation ? Or is there no significant memory gain ? Declaring a variable `$conf{'conditions'}` requires less memory compared to opening and reading /config/conditions/client1.html from a file.

Comment: This is your customer database? That you have hard coded in Perl code? Why not use a database?

Comment: For such situation when you do not intend to use fully fledged SQL database your option could be [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/). You can do a quick [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_perl.htm) research on using Perl to utilize SQLite. __Note:__ installation procedure may be different for your Operating System.

Comment: If you do decide to use a database, importing the data you currently have into it should be relatively easy. Maybe put a loop around the gigantic `if` structure, looping over all the `$user` values, then just perform an INSERT for each user value and data.

Comment: Indeed I think you're right, a db table would be the first choice but the `if`-constructions are more complex than that. They also hold all kinds of user settings, custom stuff, if-elses, multi-user, etc. My question was about memory - would it be more efficient to store all the sales conditions in CONFIG.pm (2.2 MB vs. ~300 KB to load) or read them out from the filesystem, like CONDITIONS.html (only when they are needed, when generating PDF invoices or quotes)

Comment: @BartVanderDonck 2 MB is not all that much, depending on how the code is written of course. Unless you are running a lot of processes, I would not worry. Are you experiencing any problems with memory, or why do you ask?

Comment: @BartVanderDonck In terms of coding practices, having one unique function for every user is a bad idea. You want re-usability, encapsulation. Since you don't provide any detail, I can't really give advice, except to say that this solution does not sound very scalable, and hard to debug. Just the fact that the person who documents this information has to be a Perl programmer is a huge drawback. And debugging 2 MB worth of code is a huge job. What if down the line you have a 20MB file, and you realize you have to make a small change, and you have to rewrite everything in that file from scratch?

Comment: I'm asking because memory is the name of the game and every bit helps. I'm not having any issues but I don't like the idea to load 2200KB .pm for every executed .pl file while 300KB is actually enough. So at this point I'm indeed considering to leave out the sales conditions in the .pm - thanks TLP for the help!